# Immutable Object Creation in a Loop

Tags: java, garbage-collection, immutability

From my understanding creating mutable objects inside of a loop like the method below would create a bunch of objects which would the garbage collection would have to dispose of each new object.

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++){
    Object obj = new Object();
}
```

As opposed to this method which reuses the same object and doesn’t require garbage collection.

```
Object obj;
for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++){
    obj = new Object();
}
```

But what about when using immutable objects that cannot be changed after they are instantiated? The garbage collection would still have to run on these objects regardless, correct? If so, then in this case does either of these methods make any difference in regards to garbage collection and performance?

Say for example the object is a BigDecimal:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++){
    BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(someValue);
}
```

VS.

```
BigDecimal number;
for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++){
    number = new BigDecimal(someValue);
}
```

Is there any difference in these two now that we’re dealing with immutable objects?...excluding scope, I am aware of the difference in scope in these two examples. Thanks!

Comment: The first and second code snippets would still create the same number of objects in memory.

Comment: You are confusing mutating an object with reassigning a variable.

Comment: I thought that you could reassign or reuse an object without triggering garbage collection on it, but maybe I was under the wrong impression on how garbage collection works. So are there any differences between any of my examples other than simply changing the scope of the object? Thanks!

Comment: I looked at the bytecode generated for your first two examples, and it's the same. So the only difference is the scope of `obj`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, oh wow, I had no idea that scope was the only difference here, so I'm really glad I asked this question. Thank you for verifying it! I have some code to re-write now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> As opposed to this method which reuses the same object and doesn’t require garbage collection.

No, each scenario you describe will create objects that need garbage collected.

> Is there any difference in these two now that we’re dealing with immutable objects?

No.  Although some immutable objects such as `String` and `Integer` types may be cached by the VM.

Comment: Wow, really? So in my first two examples with mutable objects, is the only difference between those two examples the scope of the object? I thought there was more going on than just changing the scope, but maybe I'm wrong on that. Thanks!